# Why does the drawBitmap method in Canvas class distorts the image

Tags: android

Why does the drawBitmap() method in Canvas class distorts the image?
When I use setImageBitmap() function of ImageView to set the bitmap on a subclass of ImageView, the image is rendered perfectly.

Now there is a bug in Android 4.x and this setImageBitmap causes problem for extra menu items. The extra menu items (generally beyond six menu items that are displayed using More...) looses touch listener.

I have following code that shows how the image is rendered using two different method.

```
/**
 * draws bitmap icons
 */
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    if(bitmap == null){
       bitmap = AppMain.getItemIcon(thisItem);
    }
    //drawBitmap(canvas, bitmap); //distorts image
    drawBitmap(bitmap); //works perfect

}
    //draw using setImageBitmap
private void drawBitmap(Bitmap bitmap){
    if(bitmap != null){
        this.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        Matrix m = this.getImageMatrix();
        m.setRectToRect(new RectF(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight()), 
                        new RectF(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight()),
                        Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);

        this.setImageMatrix(m);

    }

}
    //draw using canvas.drawBitmap()
private void drawBitmap(Canvas canvas, Bitmap bitmap){
    if(bitmap != null){
        Matrix m = new Matrix();
        m.setRectToRect(new RectF(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight()), 
                        new RectF(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight()), 
                        Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);

        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, m, null);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it is just scaled up. By default `ImageView` draws scaled bitmaps using bilinear filtering. You can try enabling it when calling `Canvas.drawBitmap`. You need to create new [Paint](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html) object with [corresponding](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG) flag (but don't do this in `onDraw` method):

```
Paint mPaint = new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG);
```

And then supply this `Paint` object to the `Canvas.drawBitmap` method:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, m, mPaint);
```